# (Non)compactness of (in)definite unitary groups over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: lie-groups, compactness, linear-groups

I have heard and read in various sources that the unitary group $U(p,q)(\mathbb{R})$ is compact if and only if $p = 0$ or $q = 0$. However I don't know of a proof (or a reference for one). Is this easy to see?

Here, let $D = D_{p,q}$ be the $(p+q)\times (p+q)$ diagonal matrix with $p$-many 1's and $q$-many $-1$'s, then $U(p,q)$ is the group of matrices $g\in GL_{p+q}(\mathbb{C})$ with $g^*Dg = D$, where $\cdot^*$ denotes conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 3):

If $p,q>0$, then $U(p,q)$ contains every matrix of the type$$\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{x^2+1}&0&0&\ldots&0&0&x\\0&1&0&\ldots&0&0&0\\&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&0&1&0\\x&0&0&\ldots&0&0&\sqrt{x^2+1}\end{bmatrix},$$with $x\in\Bbb R$. So, it's unbounded, and therefore it's not compact.

Comment: Thank you for this! This is very short and clean, but it's somewhat unenlightening. Would you mind adding some remarks on how this generalizes or how you came up with this matrix?

Comment: I got this matrix by dealing with the $p=q=1$ case. That is, I searched for real matrices $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ such that$$\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix},$$and a solution that I got was $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\sqrt{x^2+1}&x\\x&\sqrt{x^2+1}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. And then I added the $0$'s and $1$'s needed to work in the general case.